# Keyboard shortcuts in editor in SO

Tags: discussion, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts

I found:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - `> text`     - Simple blockquote
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - `----------` - Horizontal rule
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> -  Code in backticks

```
`text`
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> -  `- text`  -  Bulleted  list
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> -  `1. text` - Numbered  list

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> - `*text*`   - Italic text
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - `**text**` - Bold text

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - Header 2

```
Header 2
--------
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - Header 1

```
Header 1
========
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> - Add image dialog
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - Insert hyperlink

Can I find any others? Especially I'm looking for this hotkey:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>???</kbd> - `<kbd>text</kbd>`

Thanks

Comment: There is a useful official help page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a [stackapps extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts) to have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> do `<kbd>` marking:

[image]

Comment: [kbd] shortcut is no longer in available

Answer (score 9):

When hovering over the buttons in the editor, the tooltip will also contain the keyboard shortcut:

> [image: ctrl + k tooltip for code formatting]

There is no shortcut for `<kbd>`, as it is not generally useful (and too easy to abuse). It is a rather rare thing to need.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut for `<kbd>` tag is not directly available yet. But as Anthon suggested, you can download and install the [stackapps extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts) to enable this shortcut.

You can hover over the buttons in the editor to discover their respective keyboard shortcuts. However, there are also other shortcuts outside the editor. Please check them out if you want:

#### Basic shortcuts:

<kbd>A</kbd> Answer the current question (doesn't work on other pages apart from questions)
<kbd>C</kbd> Comment on the current post
<kbd>I</kbd> Open the Inbox tab
<kbd>L</kbd> Generate Link of the current question
<kbd>R</kbd> Open the Achievement tab
<kbd>S</kbd> Go to the Search bar

<kbd>U</kbd> Jump to the question
<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> Scroll through the answers, up and down respectively.

---

#### Other shortcuts:

Pressing <kbd>G</kbd> (probably short for general or goto) being anywhere at the site opens a dialog box like thing:

[image]

Pressing <kbd>M</kbd> (short for moderation) brings the following box:

[image]

The rest are described in respective boxes.

You can order answers by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>:

[image]

Press <kbd>V</kbd> to vote:

[image]